# Particle System Halos vs Objects

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, particle-edit-mode

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fVd1osF-ZCLDb2eGdjVZdMulcxZhDndr?usp=sharing

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a solution?
When I start the particle system and the default is halo, my setup as in the first video is great, the particle comes out of the emitter nicely. But when I switch to object, the particle drops come out of nowhere randomly, and not from the eye/emitter as in the halo version

Comment: Without seeing any settings, no information about the object you are instancing etc. it is hard to tell. You say they "come out of nowhere randomly", is this really true? Or are they just somehow offset from the emitter? Is the origin of the object in the center of the mesh or somewhere else? Because the particle emitter determines where origins of an object are spawned, not the mesh. The halos have no mesh, so they are exactly where you want them. But if your object has its mesh moved offset from the origin in _Edit Mode_, then the origins are emitted in the correct place, but not the meshes.

Comment: The object position was offset, I put them in the center of the scene and aligned the origin as well, and now it's working exactly as it should. That was the issue, as you stated, the origin was not centered. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in the comments, but maybe it is interesting for others to know that there is a solution to this question:

The halos are emitted in place of the particles. An object however which has a mesh will be emitted with its **origin** where the particles are. If mesh and origin are offset from each other, the origins will be emitted correctly, but the mesh will be shown somewhere else, offset from where you expect it to be emitted:

[image: particle objects with offset origins]

To correct this you can simply select the object(s) that should be rendered from the particle emitter, then right-click and choose *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry*.